# Facebook Graph object not returning the values in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I want to display the users details in the app from facebook, 
Here is the code:

```
private String buildUserInfoDisplay(GraphUser user) {

        StringBuilder userInfo = new StringBuilder("");

        userInfo.append(String.format("Name: %s\n\n", 
            user.getName()));
        userInfo.append(String.format("Birthday: %s\n\n", 
            user.getBirthday()));
        userInfo.append(String.format("Location: %s\n\n", 
            user.getLocation().getProperty("name")));
        userInfo.append(String.format("Locale: %s\n\n", 
            user.getProperty("locale")));
        //JSONArray languages = (JSONArray)user.getProperty("languages");
        GraphObjectList<MyGraphLanguage> languages = 
                (user.cast(MyGraphUser.class)).getLanguages();
        if (languages.size() > 0) {
            ArrayList<String> languageNames = new ArrayList<String> ();

                for (MyGraphLanguage language : languages) {
                    languageNames.add(language.getName());
                }         
            userInfo.append(String.format("Languages: %s\n\n", 
            languageNames.toString()));
        }

        return userInfo.toString();
    }

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,Exception exception) 
{

        if (state.isOpened()) {
            userInfoTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.REQUESTS);
            Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback(){

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (user != null) {
                        // Display the parsed user info

                        userInfoTextView.setText(buildUserInfoDisplay(user));
                    }
                }}).executeAsync();

            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            userInfoTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
        }
    }
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: did you set the permissions on facebook api ?

Comment: is it Session.getActiveSession() ? true

Answer (score 0):

add the below code after you declare and initial YOUR Facebook LoginButton,

```
YOUR_Facebook_Loginbutton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_location", "user_birthday", "user_likes"));
```

Otherwise, check you had add the Languages information in your profile.
If the user doesn't have the data, it must be null.
You can see the languages information in your fb 'about' page -> Contact and Basic info

Hope this can help you!
Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph#userdata